# The Hibernate SessionFactory is always null when using Spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullpointerException` on my save method in `CityDaoImpl`. Seems that `sessionFactory` is not autowired since on debugging it was revealed that sessionFactory is never injected in `CityDaoImpl`. I have look through many answers but none of them could solve my problem.
This is my `HibernateConfig.xml` file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

   xsi:schemaLocation=
   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.testing" />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sybrium" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.testing.bean.City</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="cityDao" class="com.testing.dao.CityDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And this is `CityDaoImpl.java` :

```
public class CityDaoImpl implements CityDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void save(City city){
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(city);
    }

}
```

Now I am executing a unit test on my dao class. But is failing with a NPE.

```
public class TestCityDao {

    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("HibernateConfig.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
        City city = new City();
        city.setName("Karachi");
        city.setCountry("Pakistan");
        CityDao dao = (CityDao) ctx.getBean("cityDao");
        dao.save(city);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Jan 15, 2015 11:54:53 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b34bf3: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b34bf3]; startup date [Thu Jan 15 23:54:53 PKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 15, 2015 11:54:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [HibernateConfig.xml]
Jan 15, 2015 11:54:53 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b34bf3]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b8202e
Jan 15, 2015 11:54:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b8202e: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,cityDao]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 15, 2015 11:54:53 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jan 15, 2015 11:54:53 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
```

And the exception thrown is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.testing.dao.CityDaoImpl.save(CityDaoImpl.java:19)
    at com.testing.TestCityDao.test(TestCityDao.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Stack trace indicates NPE on this line: this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(city); Do you know from debugger what is exactly null?

Comment: `sessionFactory` is null. @lkarnac

Comment: Well i haven't created database schema as i expect `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=created ` to create it for me. Can this be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare the sessionFactory dependency:

```
<bean id="cityDao" class="com.testing.dao.CityDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

and then you also have:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Try removing the `@Autowired` annotation, since it's redundant if you use XML configuration.

**Just because you added the sessionFactory, it doesn't mean Spring can automatically manage Hibernate Sessions too.**

You also need to add:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

as well as:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Now you need to also add `@Transactional` to your **save** routine:

```
@Transactional
public void save(City city){
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(city);
}
```

Comment: it worked. Can you please share some resource from where I can learn more about this spring's session management. Also why I need to annotate `save` as  `@Transactional`?